remap NumLock to Right click Menu
6.10.5-arch1-1
MATE desktop (1.28.2-1)
I want to open the right-click menu under the mouse cursor using a key.
My keyboard has a menu key but that does not raise the menu at the point of the mouse cursor.
I have tried xbindkeys and xautomation with this ~/xbindkeysrc
 "xte 'key Menu'"
    Num_Lock

I have cleared all running instances of xbindkeys using pkill xbindkeys then run xbindkeys&
But it is not working.
